# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT erorr in express js

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I was working on REST API in express

I wrote a custom error handler as below in my project

```
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
 if (res.headersSent) return next(err);
 res.status(500);
 res.send("error", { error: err }); 
}
```

and i intentionally made a mistake as below to test whether my custom error handler is working

```
res.json({
 _id: user._id,
 username: user.username,
 email: user.email,
 token: generateToken(user.id, "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET", "20s"),
});

res.cookie("jwt", newRefreshToken, {
 httpOnly: true,
 secure: true,
 sameSite: "None",
 maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

**[I sent the response which already set the response header and then I again tried to set the headers by res.cookies eventually which results in headers sent error]**

Now my question is in my custom error handler I handled this error by if (res.headersSent) return next("err");

But still I am getting error and app gets crashed.

So, Please let me know how to handle this in right way.

[image]

Comment: `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` will not crash an application, it will only be logged. So if your app crashes, there's another reason why it does so.

Comment: I have edited my post and attached a snapshot of my problem

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, Express will keep running just fine when the error occurs.

Comment: Hey Robert thanks for your first comment ///// "ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT will not crash an application, it will only be logged. So if your app crashes, there's another reason why it does so" //////.At least it gave me  a clue to find out where the problem is. I Made mistake in my router callback function ,I used a async function and inside function body i didn't use  try catch block .Again thanks for your help

Comment: Good to hear you solved your problem. You can write your own answer, or close the question entirely.